# node label/key in XText when translating from grako

Tags: xtext, grako

In grako one can use the following `name:e` to add the result of e to the AST using name as key. For example

```
var_def
    =
    var+:ID {',' var+:ID}*
```

What would be a good translation of this to Xtext?
I tried

```
var_def:
     var=ID (',' var=ID)*;
```

which is not failing, but is raising the following warning

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The possibly assigned value of feature 'var' may be overridden
   by subsequent assignments.
- This assignment will override the possibly assigned value of
   feature 'var'.
```

I think I am trying to mimic the `name` behavior, but do not have much success.

Comment: Not an answer, but it's worth noting that in recent versions of Grako it is possible to write:``var:','.{ID}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your solution only the last ID will be available in the AST. I assume `var` should be a multi-valued feature holding all IDs, not only the last one. This can be expressed as

```
var_def:
    var+=ID (',' var+=ID)*;
```

In the resulting AST `var` is a list of IDs.